# Bash shell scripting. Variable as argument. No quote vs double quote

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have 2 different commands:

```
rm -rf $MY_DIR
rm -rf "$MY_DIR"
```

What is the difference between them? Which should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables are expanded verbatim, so you should use the quoted option.  Let's say your $HOME variable were equal to `/Users/rocket spacer`.  In that case, it would be the difference between running `rm -rf /Users/rocket spacer` and `rm -rf "/Users/rocket spacer"`.  The first would try to remove two things: `/Users/rocket` and `spacer` in the current directory.  The second option would do what you want, and remove the the directory `/Users/rocket spacer`.  In general, when expanding a shell variable which represents a path, you should wrap it in quotes so you don't have to worry about the possibility of anything being misinterpreted.

Comment: Also, I've seen another kind of quote, the ` quote, not the single quote '.  As seen in this answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84980. When do I use that?

Comment: That's called a backtick and everything inside of it will be evaluated and then substituted into your bash command. For example, if you wanted to print out "My name is" and the name of the current user, you could run echo "I am `whoami`"

Comment: Unfortunately, in my comment above, the backticks caused the "whoami" to be formatted as code, but what i meant is to run:   echo "I am (backtick)whoami(backtick)"

Comment: Also, see this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands